# Plotting sparklines in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, tables

I would like to use R to plot out something like this:

[image: Something like this]

It would seem possible but highly complex to keep track of the coordinates, width, height, etc. Intuitively it would seem best to treat each cell as a new plot and transform the coordinates for each cell. Is there a way to do this in R?

thanks!

Comment: You are looking for [sparklines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparkline). Searching in R for `??sparkline` shows that the packages `sparkTable` and `YaleToolkit` could be helpful.

Comment: Looking at `YaleToolkit`, appears they are using the `grid` package to create stacked sparklines. Perhaps I can use `grid` to create the table.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party on this one, but I recently had a similar question which has been answered over here with some alternative methods for standalone sparklines: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337980/r-yaletoolkit-how-to-change-the-font-size-of-tick-labels-on-the-sparklines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337980/r-yaletoolkit-how-to-change-the-font-size-of-tick-labels-on-the-sparklines)

Comment: Check `??sparkline` and [formattable](http://www.magesblog.com/2016/01/formatting-table-output-in-r.html) will helps.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I initially managed to produce something approaching your original picture with some quick and dirty R code (see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/868376)), until I discovered that the [sparkTable](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sparkTable/index.html) package should do this very much better, provided you are willing to use $\LaTeX$. (In the meantime, it has also been pointed out by @Bernd!)

Here is an example, from `help(sparkEPS)`:

[image]

It should not be too difficult to arrange this the way you want.